# Create a new project using outputs from Terraformer

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

Currently trying out a tool called Terraformer (it's a reverse Terraform) - https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/terraformer.

I have a simple GCP project called ***test-one*** which only has one resource, vm_instance (google_compute_instance). I ran Terraformer and managed to get the outputs:

```
$ generated/google/test-one/instances/us-central1
.
├── compute_instance.tf
├── outputs.tf
├── provider.tf
└── terraform.tfstate
```

My question is - What should I do next if say I want to have the same exact configuration but for a new group that I'm going to name as ***test-two***?

Should I go to each file, replace anything that has the string "test-one" to "test-two", and then perform `terraform plan` and `terraform apply`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a [terraform module](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/modules.html) which will deploy whatever enviroment you want and will take as few parameters as possible, only name (e.g: "test-two") if possible.

Converting your current state to use module is not the easiest , but is usually possible without destroying any resource when using `terraform import`

I would also recommend watching this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wgzgVm7Sqlk)